# Побитное изменение файла?

Tags: python

Итак, есть простенькая программа на питоне конвертированная в .exe:

```
import pyautogui as pg
pg.alert("текст какой-то", "тестовое окно", "ок")
```

Известно, что файлы состоят из битов, т.е. из 0 и 1. Нужно допустим заменить 0 на 1 и 1 на 0 в файле .exe и сохранить. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать)

P.S. пишу на питоне.

Comment: Прочитайте файл в байтовый буфер. Измените буфер. Запишите байтовый буфер в файл.

Comment: Минимальная адресуемая единица хранения информации (хоть на диске, хоть в памяти) - один байт. Если нужно изменить один бит, нужно прочитать нужный байт, изменить в нем бит, записать байт обратно на то же место.  Открываете в режиме "rb+" (чтение и запись в бинарном режиме), перейти на нужный байт (метод seek), прочитать байт (read(1)), изменить, перейти опять на тот же байт (seek), записать (write).